# Sending buyer a product key on eBay

Tags: notifications, key, product

I want to sell a product on eBay and have an active user account.

I have a product almost ready to go. The product is an installable but requires a product key that will be sent to the buyers after a successful purchase. How do I go about setting this up as, I can create a database of product keys but after that I am kind of lost.

Any ideas anyone?

(A quick look just now mentioned the eBay API, sounds like a Christmas present to me , I shall check it out )

Answer (score 0):

looks like paypal instant notification !

Voulaino!